# How to get more info on this PDO MySql error with Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db

In my PHP script I run an update statement as follows:

```
$this->_db->update('names', $data, $this->_db->quoteInto('id = ?', $obj->id));
```

The db handle is a Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract instance (of the PDO MySql variety).

The problem is that the update is failing and I can't seem to get more info on the error.

The error occurs within a try/catch block.  When I catch the error, I run:

```
$db->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile();
```

And the output is:

```
2012-11-14T22:20:02+11:00 INFO (6): Zend_Db_Profiler_Query Object
(
    [_query:protected] => begin
    [_queryType:protected] => 64
    [_startedMicrotime:protected] => 1352892002.6064
    [_endedMicrotime:protected] => 1352892002.6066
    [_boundParams:protected] => Array
        (
        )
```

I know it says no parameters are bound, but I really don't think that's the case.  I think that somehow 'last query' is not what I think it is.

Secondly, when I catch the error I also run:

```
$db->getConnection()->errorInfo();
```

And the output is:

```
2012-11-14T22:20:02+11:00 INFO (6): Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

Obviously this is not very helpful.

Any ideas?  How can I get more info on the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force PDO to throw exceptions with all the info:

```
<?php

$this->_db->->getConnection()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


try {
    $this->_db->update('names', $data, $this->_db->quoteInto('id = ?', $obj->id));
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    print_r($ex);
}
```